# How do I get my Tumbleweed question answered?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, tumbleweed-badge

I asked a question a couple weeks ago and received no responses.  It got me the Tumbleweed badge, in fact.  I'd still like to get an answer, if possible, to the question.  I've updated the question with some additional information that I've discovered in the past 3 weeks, but my problem remains.  How do I get other Stack Overflow users to revisit my question (ie, how do I get it to come back to the top of the list of questions on the board)?

EDIT: I've just added a bounty to my question.  Though it appears in the featured questions list, it is at the very bottom.  Will anyone see it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348850/asp-net-clientformsauthenticationmembershipprovider-possible-json-problem

Comment: Thanks, all.  This issue became moot, for after weeks of poking at the original problem, I solved it myself (and posted the answer).  But I'm happy I posted here and learned a few tips on using SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you need to do is make sure it's tagged correctly.  Make sure you're using tags that are commonly used on this site for your topic area.  That's how users who are knowledgeable in your subject area will notice the question.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the bounty: it will move upwards in the featured-list as the bounty deadline approaches, so it will get more and more exposure.

Comment: (+1) So, it makes sense that my question is the very last question on the bounty list.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you edit the question. It will pop to the frontpage. Since the frontpage is questions sorted by last modification time.

Also the community user will on occasion bump old questions to the frontpage free of charge. How very nice of him :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other fine suggestions here, you may want to look at your question and see if there isnt' a better way to rephrase the title and/or more optimally ask the question.

Comment: Good point: when I looked at it initially I moved on because it was too long and I didn't have enough time to go through it at the moment.

Comment: @Joel - +1 thanks for retagging.  I'll try to shorten the title, perhaps, to something a little less complicated.

Comment: It wasn't the title: it was the question itself.